# Are there any downsides to the singleton pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is so bad about Singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
>   [Problems with Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392315/problems-with-singleton-pattern)

Are there any downsides to the singleton pattern? I heard this was an interview question and i am coming up short on what was meant.

imho, it's about the usage and nothing in the pattern itself is problematic

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the pattern. But it is probably the pattern that is most misused when it is not appropriate.

Comment: Poss duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448393/singleton-design-pattern-pitfalls and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392315/problems-with-singleton-pattern

Comment: You should be checking to see if this has been answered already....when you type in a question using keyword(s), SO will inform you of the possible questions that matches the keyword(s), check there first before proceeding....

Comment: I don't like the way it always leaves the lid off the mayonnaise jar when it puts it back in the fridge.  And what's up with the towels all over the bathroom floor?

Comment: sorry, it didn't show up in list due to different wording perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> Some consider it an **anti-pattern**,
>   judging that it is overused,
>   introduces unnecessary limitations in
>   situations where a sole instance of a
>   class is not actually required, and
>   introduces global state into an
>   application.

Personally, since I've started using Spring to auto-wire my application I've never had the need to write a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very generic question, it really depends on your use cases. I'd cite the following:

- You always need a mutex (or synchronized block) to protect the initial getInstance() call, which can be problematic in some cases.
- It is a hack to hide the fact that you are creating a global variable, and global variables are *generally* bad. However, there are many cases where the simplicity that they bring is appreciable, but pay attention not to abuse them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not testable or at least it's difficult
2. Hard to find dependent classes
3. Does not allow subclassing
4. ...