# PHP global object

Tags: php, mysql, singleton, oop

I have a Singleton pattern Database object which I would like to declare once for use within the system. I have a main include file which serves up all of the separate class files and also makes some global variables.

Here's the include file:

```
<?php
// Main API. We want to include everything here and then make some Global Vars:
require_once('database.class.php');

// Create the DB here:
$database = Database::Singleton();

require_once('user.class.php');
require_once('settings.class.php');

// Start the session:
session_start();
?>
```

In theory, `$database` should be a global variable accessible by anything included thereafter (i.e. `user.class.php` and `settings.class.php`. However, when I try to call a method in the `Database` class from the `User` class as follows:

```
$result = $database->FetchObject($queryString);
```

I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function NumRows() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.4.0\www\PC Estimating\classes\user.class.php on line 122**

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: *(related)* [What are the disadvantages of using a PHP database class as singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124412), [How is testing the Registry Pattern or Singleton hard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283102), [Who needs Singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964), [Why Singletons have no use in PHP](http://gooh.posterous.com/singletons-in-php), [Singletons are pathological liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to use the `$database` object from inside a method of a class, you must use the **`global`** keyword, so the `$database` variable is visible from the method :

```
class User {
    function myMethod() {
        global $database;
        
        // Work with $database
        
    }
}
```

For more informations, take a look at the [**Variable scope**][1] section of the manual.

Another *(better)* solution, considering you are use a singleton, would be to get that object from the singleton :

```
class User {
    function myMethod() {
        $database = Database::Singleton();
        
        // Work with $database
        
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rinuwise & Gordon : I've edited my answer while you were posting your comments *(didn't notice the singleton, at first)* ; thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PascalMARTIN. I have adopted your second example for my code. I will accept this one as the answer when it allows me to!

Answer (score 1):

What's the rest of your code? Specifically in `user.class.php` and `settings.class.php`. If you want to use $database in one of your class methods, you'll need to either include `global $database;` at the top of the method (this is bad, don't do it), or rely on the singleton behaviour and use `$database = Database::Singleton();` again. If the singleton is correctly set up, this should refer to the same instance as you originally created.