# Better way of accessing global class objects C++

Tags: c++, singleton, global

I have an error log class that I use throughout all the files in my project. It allows me to debug and have a greater understanding of what my code is doing. I declare it globally in main.cpp by saying Log errorLog and then use it accordingly. Now, I have been splitting files into multiple files and the way I have always gotten away with using my logger in multiple files by using "extern Log errorLog" and it works great.

Now, I am trying to figure out a way I can do this without simply including an extern at the top. A friend mentioned something about a singleton pattern. Can anyone explain this concept? Does anyone have a different concept that will work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stay with the `extern` and forget about singletons, asap please. Pretend you never heard of them. :) Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86690/500104) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392387/500104).

Another possibility is to pass your logger into every function and class that needs it, as even with `extern`, a global is still a global, and [global variables are considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

Comment: Thank you. I will continue to reference them using extern.